# Can Application Insights be used with a Linux Web App running .NET Core 3 runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

I am adding an Azure Application Service Plan to my resource group.  I'd like it to be a Linux Host for a .NET Core 3 Web API.  Furthermore, I'd like to use Application Insights.  However, when using the Azure Portal, the option to add Application Insights to a Linux .NET Core 3 application is greyed out.  Does Application Insights not currently support.  I have another Linux Web App that is using Node LTS as it's runtime and that allowed me to add Application Insights with no issue.  Is there something special I need to do to add Application Insights to a .NET Core 3 Web API running in an Azure Linux Web App?

EDIT:
Here are some screenshots of what I am seeing
[image: Basics Tab]
[image: Monitoring Tab]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Code-less enablement of Application Insights for Asp.Net core is not yet supported for linux.
You need to do code-based enablement, which involves installing SDK nugets to your project as documented below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core

Update:
Linux support is added for .NET 6.0 onwards. Check doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps-net-core?tabs=Linux%2Cwindows

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core), yes!

> Supported scenarios The Application Insights SDK for ASP.NET Core can monitor your applications no matter where or how they run. If your
>   application is running and has network connectivity to Azure,
>   telemetry can be collected. Application Insights monitoring is
>   supported everywhere .NET Core is supported. Support covers:
>
> Operating system: Windows, Linux, or Mac. Hosting method: In process
>   or out of process. Deployment method: Framework dependent or
>   self-contained. Web server: IIS (Internet Information Server) or
>   Kestrel. Hosting platform: The Web Apps feature of Azure App Service,
>   Azure VM, Docker, Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), and so on. .NET Core
>   Runtime version: 1.XX, 2.XX, or 3.XX IDE: Visual Studio, VS Code, or
>   command line.  Note
>
> > If you are using ASP.NET Core 3.0 along with Application Insights,
> >     please use the 2.8.0 version or higher. This is the only version that
> >     supports ASP.NET Core 3.0.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the screenshots of what I am seeing, do you know if there is an explanation for what I am seeing there?  I read the docs and it looks like there should be no issue, but, for some reason, I can't create the App Insights instance with the Web App in this configuration.  I wonder if this is an Azure bug, or is there a reason?

Comment: Ooops, you're right. experiencing the same issue. If you have some patience, add an issue on the docs page's bottom. Would you be able to setup your AppInsights environment in a seperate step and only use the it's API key in you code? This should work as that's afiak the only magic behind.

Comment: I definitely can, I just was worried that if I wasn't allowed to from the portal automatically, would I run into issues later because something wasn't bound correctly to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-instrumentation for Application Insights for .NET Core apps is a high priority and work is planned to support the functionality. Stay tuned! Your feedback and patience are greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Is this still something that's in the works? I still cannot see it being auto instrumented nor an option to enable it.