# Azure Application Insights Greyed Out but logs are populating

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, .net-5

I have an app service running in azure. The app service is running a linux container running a .NET 5 app service.

I have added the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore Nuget.

I have added the AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() to my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}
```

The Instrument key is being added to the app service configuration in azure using the variable 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'

If i go into my resource group and open the Application Insights resource directly i can see all the logs without any issue. However when i go into my app service resource the Application Insights link is greyed out. Any ideas why i cant navigate to the app insights resource from my app service?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's resulting from it [hasn't supported code-less mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview#supported-environments-languages-and-resource-providers) for linux. There's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59293308) to this situation. And it's true that you can only install sdk to set up app insights here.

[image]